# Multiple jquery references before and after '$.noConflict'?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I work on a big project that spans thousands of PHP files. In it, there are multiple references to jquery that are interfering with a plugin that I'm trying to implement.

For example, let's look at this markup:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script
       src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
       integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script
       src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
       integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.somePluginIamImplementing.min.js"></script>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="example"></div>

        <script>
        $.noConflict();
            jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
                // code works perfectly like this!
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see, I have multiple references to jquery, but this is not an issue since I called noConflict which returns the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version.

However, since the project consists of many dynamically created PHP files, there are few more references to jquery after the noConflict line I wrote, something like this:

```
<div id="example"></div>

    <script>
        $.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
            // code works perfectly like this!
        });
    </script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-Ls0pXSlb7AYs7evhd+VLnWsZ/AqEHcXBeMZUycz/CcA="
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

As a result, I get an error in console.log TypeError: $(...).somePluginIamImplementing is not a function.

How can I use only the version of jquery I like in order to initialize the plugin?

Comment: It is hard to reproduce the problem. It is not clear what is your plugin and where you are trying to apply it. Please create a jsfiddle or executable code example here, which causes this error.

Comment: So sorry for the conditions you have to work in... On topic - the only viable solution is huge refactoring with moving all possible jquery code into page footer. A template engine, like Twig, would help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try assigning different calls of `jQuery.noConflict` to different variables.

Whatever plugins that are loaded up to the next version of jquery loaded will be attached to the version of jQuery represented by each noConflict variable

Example using same plugin loaded along with each individual version of jQuery but note each version of the plugin gets bound to it's associated jQuery version

Passing `$` as parameter into each ready function makes $ usable as current version

```js
$jQ1(function($) {
  $('#example').myPlugin()
});
$jQ2(function($) {
  $('#example').myPlugin()
})
$jQ3(function($) {
  $('#example').myPlugin()
})
$jQ4(function($) {
  $('#example').myPlugin()
})


jQuery(function($){
  $('#example').append($('<p>',{text:'Last version jQuery loaded in page is '+$.fn.jquery}))
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    (function($) {
      $.fn.myPlugin = function() {        
          $('<p>', {text: 'jQuery version in plugin: ' + $.fn.jquery}).appendTo(this);        
      }
    })(jQuery)
  </script>
  <script>
    $jQ1 = jQuery.noConflict();
  </script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $jQ2 = jQuery.noConflict();
  </script>
  <script>
    (function($) {
      $.fn.myPlugin = function() {        
          $('<p>', {text: 'jQuery version in plugin: ' + $.fn.jquery}).appendTo(this);        
      }
    })(jQuery)
  </script>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $jQ3 = jQuery.noConflict();
  </script>
  <script>
    (function($) {
      $.fn.myPlugin = function() {        
          $('<p>', {text: 'jQuery version in plugin: ' + $.fn.jquery}).appendTo(this);        
      }
    })(jQuery)
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="example"></div>

  <script>
  </script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    (function($) {
      $.fn.myPlugin = function() {        
          $('<p>', {text: 'jQuery version in plugin: ' + $.fn.jquery}).appendTo(this);        
      }
    })(jQuery)
  </script>
  <script>
    $jQ4 = jQuery.noConflict();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```